# I'm getting a "Runtime Error" trying to access stackoverflow.com

Tags: support

I'm not able to access stackoverflow.com at all, it keeps throwing a Runtime error. I'm not sure what to do.

Here's the error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Runtime Error
>
> Description: An exception occurred while processing your request.
>   Additionally, another exception occurred while executing the custom
>   error page for the first exception. The request has been terminated.

**Update:**

Here is the screenshot

URL: https://stackoverflow.com/ or any link (Questions, etc.) that leads to stackoverflow.com

[image: URL: https://stackoverflow.com/]

Comment: Not reproduced here.

Comment: do trace route, ping also check [CurrentlyDown](http://www.currentlydown.com/). Also what region/country are you from?

Comment: Voting to close this as "norepro" because it literally cannot be re-produced is logical in one sense, but do consider that the site offers "support" and we should arguably be trying to resolve this for the user. Perhaps it would be better on MSO, and with a [support] tag, so different close votes/migrate/edit/etc/

Comment: I'm from India, now it seems to be alright, but it's still intermittent.

Comment: Related? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263697/connection-to-stackexchange-sites-failing-intermitently-today

Comment: Update: Still seeing the issue, can't access the website. Any possible reason behind the runtime exception?

Comment: What is the exact url? Screen shot?

Comment: @PatrickHofman updated, the question with screenshots. URL: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can you start a browser session in incognito mode with all plugins you might have disabled?

Comment: @pee just to be sure: did you hit refresh or did you really navigate to the front-page?

Comment: Navigated to the page.