# Connection to StackExchange sites failing intermitently today

Tags: bug, connectivity

Sorry if this already was reported. But it seems that at least some StackExchange are suffering with some technical difficulties and intermitencies in the last 24 hours or so. If this information is relevant, I am trying to access it in São Paulo, Brazil.

See those screenshots:

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

I also got a similar screen once in the astronomy site, but unfortunately I accidentally closed the tab before screenshoting it.

Further, I am getting frequent errors when trying to fetch comments, post comments, post answers and editing answers. Also, once I got a truncated partially rendered page.

BTW, the very page that I am using now to post this question have a blank text editing toolbar (although the buttons are working and clickable, they are just not visible), probably due to some networking problem. See the following screenshot:

[image: Error 3]

The other sites in my internet connection seems to working normally. The problem seems to be happening just with StackExchange.

Edited, while trying to edit this very post to fix a typo, I got this:

[image: Error 4]

Comment: I have seen one other report and if I recall it correctly it was from your area in the world (based on seeing Sao Paulo in the screenshot). Let me find it .... [from brazil](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/302086/578411) ... looks like a different root-cause but both incidents involve CloudFlare... we have to wait for @Nick to investigate...

Comment: @rene Thanks for the link.

Comment: @rene http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4225/132

Comment: I hope Nick brings his Portuguese dictionary ;)

Comment: I'm getting it across all SE sites as well, also from Brazil, and also only SE. Every third link I open ends up looking like the screenshots...

Comment: Update: This is still an issue for me.